# Metatrader5 error when loggin in with Python, error code (-10005, 'IPC timeout'

Tags: python, metatrader5

I am trying to login to Metatrader5 account and I have been receiving this error code.

Please see code below;

I first import necessary libraries and initialize which works fine

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5

mt5.initialize()
```

But when I try to log in using the below code, I receive this error -

failed to connect at account #51166970, error code: (-10005, 'IPC timeout')
In [14]:

```
account=51166970

authorized=mt5.login(account, password='z6kjjrtr', server='ICMarketsSC-Demo')

if authorized:

    print(mt5.account_info())

    print("Show account_info()._asdict():")

    account_info_dict = mt5.account_info()._asdict()

    for prop in account_info_dict:

        print("  {}={}".format(prop, account_info_dict[prop]))

else:

    print("failed to connect at account #{}, error code: {}".format(account, mt5.last_error()))
```

I also read some post about similar errors which asked I specify the path, please see post links ([MetaTrader5 libarary in Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028717/metatrader5-libarary-in-python-3-7) and [MT5/Metatrader 5 connect to different MT5 terminals using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975284/mt5-metatrader-5-connect-to-different-mt5-terminals-using-python) and https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/438477), so I edited my code but received this error - initialize() failed, error code = (-10005, 'IPC timeout')

As noted in an answer here ([metatrader error initialize() failed, error code = (-10005, 'IPC timeout')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492735/metatrader-error-initialize-failed-error-code-10005-ipc-timeout/72851156#72851156)) I changed my path from

"C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\terminal64.exe"

to

"C:/Program Files/MetaTrader 5/terminal64.exe"

```
#start the platform with initialize()
if not mt5.initialize("C:/Program Files/MetaTrader 5/terminal64.exe", login=22000642, password="duzhhjkd8", server="Deriv-Demo"):   
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
else:
    mt5.login(login=22000642, password='duzhhjkd8', server='Deriv-Demo')
```

How can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody runs into this error, I resolved it by downloading mt5 from my broker's website.

Open the downloaded app, then I went to file - add an account -

I typed the server name and put in my login details.

That solved the problem